# apply tensorflow probability model on spark dataset

Tags: tensorflow, pyspark, tensorflow-probability

I'm using the sts from tensorflow probability to generate forecast, which perform well on a sample of data I used, but I want now to try it on a wider scope and so I would like to implement in PySpark the sts model.

I have a dataset which look like that:

| Id | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 01/02/2021 | 15 |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | 11 |
| 2 | 01/01/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 01/02/2021 | 120 |
| 2 | 01/03/2021 | 90 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to find a way to create a forecast for each id (having the same amount of entries) and need to apply the model I build before to each one, what would be the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using pandas_udf in pyspark:

```
# Create the pandas udf:
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def Forecast(pdf):
        # From a pandas dataframe create a serie with timestamp as index
        pdf = pdf.sort_values(by=['Date'])

        PTS = pdf.drop(columns=['Id'])

        PTS.set_index("date", inplace=True)
        PTS.index = utils.add_freq(PTS.index, 'MS')
        PTS.loc[:, 'value'] = PTS.loc[:, 'value'].astype(float)

        _train = PTS['value'][PTS.index < Split_Date]
        train = _train.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

        forecast_distribution = utils.myForecast(train)

        fcst_mu = forecast_distribution.mean().numpy()[..., 0]

        list_date = pdf.loc[pdf['Date'] >= Split_Date, 'Date'].tolist()
        for i in range(len(list_date)):
            pdf.loc[pdf['Date'] == list_date[i], 'QTY'] = fcst_mu[i]

        return pdf

# Apply the function per group of Id:
df= df.groupby('Id').apply(Forecast)
```

Where `myForecast` is a STS model created in another file and `add_freq` is a function adding the period.